# Find Length of string without counting spaces

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, strlen

I'm making program that finds length of string entered by user. Everything is working but program also counts spaces. So, how to find length of string without counting spaces?

Comment: Add an `if` to ignore the spaces. Is this homework?

Comment: Something like `if (*c != ' ') count++;`? I'm sure you can do it.

Comment: There's [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) in `ctype.h` header catching *any* whitespace including tabulator, carriage return, newline and others.

Comment: Alternative to `if(...) ++count;` is `count += *c != ' ';`, by the way.

Comment: What about punctuation characters? Would you want to exclude these as well? `count += isalnum((unsigned char)*c);`, including digits, or `isalpha` without digits – note: the cast to unsigned is necessary for the case your strings contains symbols with numeric values > 127, as `char` potentially is signed (for `isspace` alike!).

Comment: @Aconcagua `count += *c != ' ';` is pretty hacky IMO.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Why? Comparisons being *guaranteed* to result in either 0 or 1 makes that pretty self-explanatory in my eyes, and fully portable as well – would we need to assume lack of such knowledge?

Comment: @Aconcagua if you want make code harder to read you can ` for(; *c; c++, length += *c != ' ');` or     `while(length += *c != ' ', *(++c));`

Comment: @Aconcagua separate line makes code reading easier

Comment: @Aconcagua sorry, I wasn't clear enough. Your code is perfectly correct and portable, but not very readable (at least for beginners).

Comment: @0___________ Well, with that argument `if(*c != ' ') length++;` in one single line as in your answer is just as bad – I'd qualify even worse, as at a very first glance body of the `if` appears to be lacking...

Comment: @Aconcagua short single statement `if` bodies are done this way for years

Comment: @0___________ And is *not* accepted by so many coding guide lines, including those widespread ones like MISRA (that actually even mandate placing braces).

Comment: @0___________ For your early comment: Question is now where we cross the frontier to the territory of exaggeration...

Comment: @Aconcagua I do not think that he will start work soon as a programmer in the automotive industry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the correct types for sizes
2. `*(p + x)` === `p[x]` - where `p` is a pointer and `x` has integral type. Your both function are exactly the same.
3. Use names that have some meaning `string_array` is not too informative and definitely does not indicate that it is returning the length of the string without spaces.
4. do not use `gets` functions as it is very dangerous. Use functions that limit the number of characters placed in the string. For example `fgets`

```
size_t strlenNoSpaces(const char * restrict c)
{
    size_t length = 0;
    for(; *c; c++)
    {
        if(*c != ' ') length++;
    }
    return length;
}

int main()
{
    char string[30];
    size_t length, i;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets(string, 29, stdin);

    length = strlen(string);
    printf("\nLength of string using strlen.\n");
    printf("Length of string %zu.\n", length);

    length = strlenNoSpaces(string);
    printf("\nLength of string not counting the spaces.\n");
    printf("Length of string %zu.\n", length);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @sefisko: Note that `fgets` requires a limit of one less than available array length as the limit refers to the numbers of characters actually read, but input still gets null-terminated afterwards (thus 30 <-> 29).

Comment: And `sizeof(string) - 1` would be better than `29` here, too.  And I personally avoid calling variables `string` in C code - it's a keyword in far to many other languages.  And imagine some poor noob pastes this code into some CS50 problem - the variable name `string` itself the collides with CS50's abomination of a  `typedef`...